# Optimality condition for the critical points

Tags: optimization, quadratics, quadratic-forms, optimal-control

Given the Differential equation 
$$\begin{cases}
-f'=A f \\
f(T)=f_T
\end{cases}$$
And given the quadratic functional:
$$J(f_T)=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^T|f|^2dt$$
I want to know why $$\int_0^T<f,u> dt=0$$
 is the optimality condition for the critical points of $J$

Comment: Is $f$ a vector and $A$ a square matrix? Also, how do you define $u$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you meant $J(f)$ in your definition, not $J(f_T)$ (the functional does not depend only on the terminal point). A first step toward deriving the Euler-Lagrange equation is
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{d\varepsilon}\bigg|_{\varepsilon = 0}\int_0^T |f+\varepsilon u|^2 dt &= 
\int_0^T \frac{d}{d\varepsilon}\bigg|_{\varepsilon = 0} \langle f+\varepsilon u, f+\varepsilon u\rangle  dt \\
&= \int_0^T \langle u , f+\varepsilon u \rangle + \langle f+\varepsilon u, u\rangle\bigg|_{\varepsilon = 0} dt\\
&= \int_0^T 2\langle u,f \rangle dt.
\end{align*}
Throwing in the remaining factor of $1/2$ gives what you want. You need additional conditions on $u$, in particular that $u(T) = 0$ (if indeed you meant a terminal condition).